# Regex to allow only string but not word "test"

Tags: asp.net, regex

`^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{2,40}$"` is the original regex used for firstname field in my project. I want to modify this `regex` such that it will not allow 'test' As an input.

`"^(?!^test$)(^.*$)");"` works fine to exclude word 'test' but it allows spaces & numbers. so what will be the regex which will allow only string as an input but will not allow word 'test' i.e. first name may not be 'test' ?

Comment: Your initial regex also allows whitespaces. If you want to avoid matching `test` and whitespace, use `^(?!test$)[a-zA-Z'.]{2,40}$`

Comment: hey thanks. spaces are ok, just want to avoid numbers & firstname cant be 'test'. firstname can be tesdtkkkkd but cannot be 'test'

Comment: Then just add the lookahead to your current regex -   `^(?!test$)[a-zA-Z'.\s]{2,40}$`. This regex cannot match digits.

Comment: Hey thanks it's working! :-)

Comment: Great, I added an answer, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!test$)[a-zA-Z'.\s]{2,40}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tB2tT0/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!test$)` - the string cannot equal `test`
- `[a-zA-Z'.\s]{2,40}` - 2 to 40 symbols that are ASCII letters, `'`, `.` or whitespace
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Hi, how cam i exclude all combinations of 'test'? means Test, test, TEst, tEst etc. etc. also i dont want to allow any special character

Comment: If the regex is executed at server side use `(?i)^(?!test$)[a-zA-Z'.\s]{2,40}$`. Else, you can only spell it out with negated character classes like `^(?![Tt][eE][sS][tT]$)[a-zA-Z'.\s]{2,40}$`.